# React - cannot set value of input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Calculate({ work }) {

    var inputValue = 0;

    const totalAmountToBePaid = () => {
        inputValue++;
        console.log("=====> Total Amount To Be Paid", work);
        console.log(inputValue);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <header className="App-header">
                <input type="number" id="amount" value={inputValue} readOnly></input>
                <button onClick={totalAmountToBePaid}>Total Amount To Be Paid</button>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Calculate;
```

When I click the `button`, I need it to update value of the `input` by calling the `totalAmountToBePaid` function.

The above solution just leave the value of the `input` on its default value of 0.

I am new to React, so please excuse my ignorance.  I think I might need to gave a `state` object.

Thank you

Comment: React updates DOM once the state is changed, so you should add inputValue to the state inorder to reflect the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the state object.

Replace it with following

```
function Calculate({ work }) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(0)

    const totalAmountToBePaid = () => {

      setInputValue(inputValue+1);

        console.log("=====> Total Amount To Be Paid", work);
        console.log(inputValue);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <header className="App-header">
                <input type="number" id="amount" value={inputValue} readOnly></input>
                <button onClick={totalAmountToBePaid}>Total Amount To Be Paid</button>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Working Example https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-pine-9hk26

Since you are new to React, I think you should go through React docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html to understand basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the console.logs you can just do;

`const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);`

`<button onClick={() => setInputValue(inputValue+1)}>Total Amount To Be Paid</button>`